# Building sits or building stands?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is the sentence correct 
" We don't need a parliament.Build a temple where the building stands." 
or will it be 
" We don't need a parliament.Build a temple where the building sits." 
Will it depend on the height of building or something?

Comment: Both are used. I think “sits” fallutes lower than “stands”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sits" is more passive than "stands".

> **Sit 9a:** to have a location
> **Sit 10:** to remain inactive or quiescent
>
> **Stand 2a:** to take up or maintain a specified position or posture
> **Stand 2b:** to maintain one's position
> **Stand 8b:** to occupy a place or location
>
> — Merriam, *Webster's New Collegiate Dictionary*, 1975

In the context of a building, "sits" simply implies *located on*, while "stands" indicates something that is *permanent and immovable*.

Saying "sits" emphasizes the location, while "stands" emphasizes the building.

E.g. "The cottage sits on the wooded shore of a pristine lake." vs. "The gleaming Buddhist monastery stands on the mountain top."

I think that in your sentence, it is the location that is more important, so I'd use "sits".

Comment: Then there's 'The building lies ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Now that you mention it, there’s also *the building **runs** from ... to ...*.

Comment: You need to add the etymology of 'stand', which (along with dictionary definitions of the appropriate senses) would support your claim in the first sentence. I was about to claim that both 'stand' and 'sit' are used metaphorically here, but it seems more likely that 'stand' has always been used for non-sentient (and non-legged) entities.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "**sit**" and "**stood**" depends on *permanence*.

definition

> **sit**:
> *be or remain in a particular position or state*
>
> **stand:**
> *be situated in a particular place or position*

"**Sit**" and "**stood**" seem to differ in degree of permanence.

Either would work, but "**stood**" is more appropriate given the context.

---

Here are two phrases as an example:

**1**. *the building once **stood** next to Piedmont Park*
**2**. *the building once **sat** next to Piedmont Park*

> Phrase **1** suggests that the building no longer exists.  Phrase **2** could suggest that the park (not the building) no longer exists. "**Sit**" implies more permanence than "**stood**".

Comment: Hello, Allison. Please link and attribute quotes. / The first two dictionaries (AHD and Collins) I checked in just had 'be situated or located' for the appropriate sense of 'sit' and 'stand', unlike Lexico,  and I don't think that 'remain' really connotes lifespan too heavily ('stand', after all, has the 'resist attack' sense to bolster it connotationally).

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by your examples. I think the first phrase could also suggest that the park no longer exists, e.g. _the building once stood next to Piedmont Park_ and now overlooks the new civic center.

Answer (score 0):

Buildings that stand somewhere tend to stand there for a long time. Buildings that sit somewhere, on the other hand, are easy targets for clearing, if one needs the space (to build a temple, perhaps).

Comment: Hello, Marcus. Have you supporting references for this claim? Answers on ELU need such; otherwise, they can come across as (and often are) mere opinion. 'The Tower of London sits on the banks of the Thames' seems a counter-example.

Comment: They're both correct, so this *is* a matter of opinion.

Comment: If questions only allow for answers that are opinion, they should be close-voted, not answered.

Comment: Well, I'll remember that for when I ask an opinion-based question, but right now I think the guy to talk to is the one who posted it, as he's allowing these answers instead of close-voting.

Comment: This question _isn't_ totally opinion-based.  The etymology of 'stand' shows that there has been a continuous 'abide / resist attack' sense. So I agree that half your answer is likely. But Ray posted it first.